# .net replacement for Maven

Tags: .net

Came across this today:
[NuPack](http://nupack.codeplex.com/)

Pretty new, but curious if anyone has tried it out and if we finally have a viable tool similar to the Java world's Maven

Comment: Did you get stuff running? NPanday an option? I'd be happy to help if it is still anyhow current :)

Comment: Kind of using a mix of different stuff, including NuPack and Octopus. http://octopusdeploy.com/

Answer (score 1):

I just want to confirm that NuPack is not specific to web apps.  I suggest you use the discussion forum http://nupack.codeplex.com/discussions for all NuPack questions, as it'll get more attention there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

nupack seems like a asp.net mvc module installer like ruby gems.

for mavenlike tool in .net;

NPanday : is active

Byldan : seems dead

NMaven : seems dead

my best

Serdar Irmak

Comment: Description says "NuPack is an integrated package management tool for adding libraries and tools to their .NET projects. I". Doesn't say if its ASP.NET MVC only.

Comment: you're right http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+ScottHanselman+(Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com)